# asp.net mvc 3 razor custom helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

ok i have a helper method posthelper in helper class in helper folder in asp.net mvc 3. how to call it in the razor view and use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the namespace is registered in the web.config under Views:

```
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
        <add namespace="SharpArch.Web.Areas"/>
        <add namespace="MyProject.Web.Helpers"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

alternatively use at the top of your View

```
@using MyProject.Web.Helpers
```